# How can I make transpose till particular value of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

My data frame:

```
column_data = [33.5,"W","A to B, OK","slinks down to hammer","T c V b Rell 10 (82b 6x1) DW:84.14",
33.4,"•","A to B, no","Tosses it uo",
33.3,2,"A to B, 2 R","On a right way","slinks down to hammer","BAN: 185/4CRR: 5.60 ","T 69 (80b 6x4)","Mu 7 (17b)","Mark 6-0-29-1","George Dockrel","Bet 31",
33.2,2,"A to T, 2 R","slinks down to hammer",
33.1,"2","A to T, 2 r","angling away, cuts it"]
df = pd.DataFrame(column_data, columns=['Col1'])
```

I want to make it like this:'
[image]

I tried this way but not getting as I desire:
import pandas as pd

```
num_columns = 11
num_rows = len(data2) // num_columns

data_dict = {}
for i in range(1, num_columns + 1):
    column_name = 'Col{}'.format(i)
    column_values = data2.iloc[(i - 1) * num_rows: i * num_rows, 0].tolist()
    data_dict[column_name] = column_values

df5 = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df5
```

Answer (score 2):

If the first column is always the only column with floats, which appears to be the case in your sample data, then the following code would work:

```py
# determines splits for different rows based on floats
rows = (df.Col1.map(type)==float).cumsum()

df1 = df.groupby(rows).agg(list)\
    .Col1.astype(str).str[1:-1]\
        .str.split(',', expand=True)\
            .add_prefix("col_")
```

This groups by the rows (calculated by finding floats in the column), and creates a list for each row.  The list is converted to a string, and split by "," to columns - this is because the lists are not of equal length.  A prefix is added to match the columns in your picture (although numbers are `-1`).

If the assumption of only floats in column 1 and always floats in column 1 is incorrect, then you will need some way of distinguishing where each row starts in the list.

Your code does not work because it assumes that there are an equal number of items in the list for each row - which is not the case as there are no `None` values for empty dataframe cells, so the column cannot be split evenly by 11 to return the desired result.